# How to tell the difference between an inherited class and its parent at runtime in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, extends, runtime-type

I wish to do a check if a particular variable is of type `A`, or of type `B` (which extends `A`).

In the debugger I can hover over my variable `b` and see that is is of type `B` - however in the code I don't know how to check that.

If I use `b is A` the value is `true`.
If I use `b.runtimeType is B` the value is `false`.

###### How can I check if a variable is a particular class `B`, distinct from the class `A` that it extends ?

```dart
class A {}
class B extends A {}

void main() {
  A a = A();
  B b = B();
  print('b is B : ${b is B}');
  print('b.runtimeType is B : ${b.runtimeType is B}');
  print('b is A : ${b is A}');
  print('b.runtimeType is A : ${b.runtimeType is A}');
}
```

```
b is B : true
b.runtimeType is B : false
b is A : true
b.runtimeType is A : false
```

###### What check could I do that would result in `b (is) B : true` and `b (is) A : false` ?

Answer (score 1):

I was given the answer while asking the question;

The type of a `runtimeType` property is actually something like '_type', but the **value** of it is the type, so a simple `==` comparison is what is needed to do the trick:

```dart
  print('b.runtimeType == B : ${b.runtimeType == B}');
  print('b.runtimeType == A : ${b.runtimeType == A}');
```

```
b.runtimeType == B : true
b.runtimeType == A : false
```

Comment: [`Object.runtimeType`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object/runtimeType.html) returns a `Type` object, and you can't use `is` with that because `is` checks if the left operand is an *instance* of the `Type` specified by the right operand.